# CD4015BE with carry?

Tags: shift-register

My question is about the [CD4015BE](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4015b.pdf) that i would really want to use in one of my projects, but i can't figure out how to make a carry out for the second register. In the datasheet they mention that it is possible, but i just can't seem to figure out how to do it. Some clues would be greatly appreciated.

[Datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4015b.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Q3 output as the data (D) input for the next shift register. Here's an example:

[image]

*Figure 1. Note the daisy-chaining of U2-A/B and U3 A/B. Source: [Sonelec-Musique](https://www.sonelec-musique.com/electronique_realisations_sequenceur_009.html).*

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't test it at the moment but I will make sure to upvote and mark as correct as soon as I have tested it. I will be testing it in two days.